# MVC3 @Html.ActionLink displays Text together with the address

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I do not know what I have done wrong but all my @Html.ActionLinks are displaying the expected text together with hyperlink instead of the text alone.

```
@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")
```

displays as

```
About(Home/About)
```

instead of

```
About
```

In the views,

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
```

displays

```
Edit(Home/Edit/4)
```

instead of the text

```
Edit
```

Any clues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an extension or DisplayTemplate that would change the default behaviour.

It looks like your second example is missing a parameter (the last null for html attributes, I also included the Controller here)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Home", new { id = item.Id }, null)
```

Comment: I have neither. The only additions I have made are helper methods and they are not related to display issues.

Comment: you're second link seems to be missing parameter for htmlAttributes, you can pass null.  I've updated answer with code

Comment: I have identified the cause. I am using [Blueprint Framework](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) and have included **print.css** in the _Layout.cshtml. The rule for visited links is as follows:
`a:link:after, a:visited:after { content: " (" attr(href) ")"; font-size: 90%; }`. And that was the cause of the weird display.

Comment: ouch.  but shouldn't you only include this print.css in print view only?

Comment: Yeah. Did it blindly. Didn't expect to behave in such a manner.

Comment: guess it makes perfect sense for printing, though hardly enough of a clue.  sometimes with these low level issues i work with a separate blank layout to ensure it is an issue in isolation and then bring in other resources until the problem appears.